# will float or floats?

Tags: future

What's the difference between 1 and 2 below?

> *1. Oil **will float** on water.*
>
> *2. Oil **floats** on water.*

The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says of the first "used to say what always happens in a particular situation or what is generally true". How then does it differ from the second in terms of meaning and use?

Comment: There are so many differences. For starters, the second has one less word. Please [edit] this to explain exactly what difference you want to know about, and what research you have done.

Comment: the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says of the first "used to say what always happens in a particular situation or what is generally true". How then does it differ from the second in terms of meaning and use?

Comment: Check any grammar for the usage and meaning of  _future simple_ and _present simple_ tenses.

Comment: Kathy. I've just checked, and found '... we do not recognise a future tense for English' [CGEL: Huddleston & Pullum]. They actually address this usage though, under _Dynamic modality_ (see answer below).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Hurry, give me anything that will hold water!" What verb tense is this?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154074/hurry-give-me-anything-that-will-hold-water-what-verb-tense-is-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CGEL, Huddleston & Pullum actually address this issue, under *Dynamic modality – Propensity*:

> *Oil will float on water*
>
> Here we are concerned with characteristic or habitual behaviour of
>   animates or general properties of inanimates. A simple present could
>   be substituted with little effect: this usage is therefore fairly
>   sharply distinct from futurity, though in many cases there is a
>   connection through conditional circumstance.... [If s]trong stress [is
>   put] on the auxiliary [it] conveys the speaker's emotive response to
>   the situation – usually exasperation, disapproval, resignation ...

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially interchangeable.  There is a subtle difference, however.

"Oil will float on water" is sometimes used to mean that the fact is sometimes true but not always.

For example, "The wolf is a carnivore, but in times of famine, the wolf will eat berries".

The second form, "oil floats on water," doesn't allow for that possibility.

Comment: *"Wolves are carnivores, but in times of famine, they eat berries."* Sounds possible to me.

Comment: This is certainly a difference in usage ('I will eat cheese if there's nothing else' vs 'I eat cheese if there's nothing else'.) The first sentence shows a resigned attitude when needs must. But how can oil have a resigned attitude?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth maybe "oil will float on water' is used to show disapproval when the speaker is admonishing the hearer for trying to do something that would ruin an experiment?

Comment: It would be the preferred choice in that case. Unstressed, though, it's nigh-on indistinguishable from the will-less variant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can the will be used in a scenario where the speaker isn't expressing a negative emotion? I suspect that the 'will' is used when the speaker has reason to believe the hearer doesn't know, or has neglected something of general validity, e.g. when he is describing what people generally do on a foreign festival.